# Rails 4: new instance creation through form_for not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, instance

This is a follow-up question on [Rails 4: new instance is created and saved to database but not displayed in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257024/rails-4-new-instance-is-created-and-saved-to-database-but-not-displayed-in-view/31257178?noredirect=1#comment50555198_31257178).

In our Rails 4 app, there are four models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :calendar
end
```

Here are the corresponding migrations:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.integer :total_calendar_count
      t.integer :owned_calendar_count

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateAdministrations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :administrations do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :calendar, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.string :role

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateCalendars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :calendars do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
        t.references :calendar, index: true, foreign_key: true
        t.date :date
        t.time :time
        t.string :focus
        t.string :format
        t.string :blog_title
        t.text :long_copy
        t.text :short_copy
        t.string :link
        t.string :hashtag
        t.string :media
        t.float :promotion
        t.string :target
        t.integer :approval
        t.text :comment

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

We have the following form to create posts:

```
<h2>Create a new post</h2>

<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

    <tr>
        <%= f.hidden_field :calendar_id, value: @calendar.id %>
        <td class="field"><%= f.date_field :date, placeholder: "When do you want to publish this post?" %></td>
        <td class="field"><%= f.time_field :time, placeholder: "What time do you want to publish this post?" %></td>
        <td class="field"><%= f.text_field :focus, placeholder: "What is this post about?" %></td>
        <td class="field"><%= f.text_field :format, placeholder: "What type of post is this?" %></td>
        <td class="field"><%= f.text_field :blog_title, placeholder: "If this post is about a blog post, what is the title of the blog post?" %></td>
        <td class="field"><%= f.text_area :long_copy, placeholder: "What is the copy of the post?" %></td>
        <td class="field"><%= f.text_area :short_copy, placeholder: "What is the short copy of the post (to be used on Twitter for instance)?" %></td>
        <td class="field"><%= f.url_field :link, placeholder: "Which link to you want to embed in this post?" %></td>
        <td class="field"><%= f.text_field :hashtag, placeholder: "Which hashtag(s) do you want to you in this post?" %></td>
        <td class="field"><%= f.text_field :media, placeholder: "Which media file (image, video) do you want to include in this post?" %></td>
        <td class="field"><%= f.number_field :promotion, placeholder: "What advertising budget should be allocated to this post?" %></td>
        <td class="field"><%= f.text_field :target, placeholder: "Who do you want to target with this post?" %></td>
        <td class="field"><%= f.select(:approval, %w['Approved' 'Needs edits' 'To be deleted'], {prompt: 'How does this post look?'}) %></td>
        <td class="field"><%= f.text_area :comment, placeholder: "Any comment?" %></td>

        <td><%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %></td>

    </tr>

<% end %>
```

This form is embedded into the `Calendars#Show` view, so that as soon as a post is created, it should appear in the corresponding calendar.

Here is our `PostsController`:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.create(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render root_url
    end
  end

end
```

Currently, whenever we submit the form, nothing happens:

- All the values stay put in the form
- The page is not reloaded (so, no error message appears)
- No new @post is added to the database

**EDIT**: here are the server logs:

```
Started GET "/calendars/1" for ::1 at 2015-07-07 22:21:07 -0700
Processing by CalendarsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Calendar Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE "calendars"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Post Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."calendar_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["calendar_id", 1]]
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."calendar_id" = ?  [["calendar_id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_post_form.html.erb (5.1ms)
  Rendered calendars/show.html.erb within layouts/application (13.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 145ms (Views: 144.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

**EDIT 2**: here are the new server logs, after implementing what @miler350 recommended in his answer:

```
Started POST "/posts" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 09:09:58 -0700
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+LS+B2/KiUq09cypZSQnzwj5xHbNnkYR6EC5hfjNCwc3/NfFkbWi3FJe0Zw3Mumsdnubnip5piQHXZ00eV1W2A==", "post"=>{"calendar_id"=>"", "date"=>"2015-08-20", "time"=>"12:04", "focus"=>"Test", "format"=>"Test", "blog_title"=>"Test", "long_copy"=>"Test", "short_copy"=>"Test", "link"=>"http://www.google.com", "hashtag"=>"Test", "media"=>"Test", "promotion"=>"50", "target"=>"Test", "approval"=>"'Approved'", "comment"=>"Test"}, "commit"=>"Create"}
Unpermitted parameter: calendar_id
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("date", "time", "focus", "format", "blog_title", "long_copy", "short_copy", "link", "hashtag", "media", "promotion", "target", "approval", "comment", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["date", "2015-08-20"], ["time", "2000-01-01 12:04:00.000000"], ["focus", "Test"], ["format", "Test"], ["blog_title", "Test"], ["long_copy", "Test"], ["short_copy", "Test"], ["link", "http://www.google.com"], ["hashtag", "Test"], ["media", "Test"], ["promotion", 50.0], ["target", "Test"], ["approval", 0], ["comment", "Test"], ["created_at", "2015-07-08 16:09:58.605712"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-08 16:09:58.605712"]]
   (0.6ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 09:09:58 -0700
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/static_pages (1.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_static_header.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 148ms (Views: 147.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)


Started GET "/users/1" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 09:10:02 -0700
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered shared/_calendar_form.html.erb (5.0ms)
  Administration Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "administrations" WHERE "administrations"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
  Administration Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "administrations".* FROM "administrations" WHERE "administrations"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  Calendar Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE "calendars"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Calendar Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE "calendars"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Calendar Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE "calendars"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Calendar Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE "calendars"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
  Calendar Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE "calendars"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  Rendered administrations/_administration.html.erb (4.1ms)
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (32.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 150ms (Views: 135.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)


Started GET "/calendars/1" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 09:10:04 -0700
Processing by CalendarsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Calendar Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE "calendars"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Post Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."calendar_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["calendar_id", 1]]
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."calendar_id" = ?  [["calendar_id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_post_form.html.erb (5.3ms)
  Rendered calendars/show.html.erb within layouts/application (13.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 113ms (Views: 111.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

**EDIT 3**: here are the server logs when I add `:calendar_id` to the permitted post_params in the `PostsControllers`:

```
Started GET "/calendars/1" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 11:07:39 -0700
Processing by CalendarsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Calendar Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE "calendars"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Post Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."calendar_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["calendar_id", 1]]
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."calendar_id" = ?  [["calendar_id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_post_form.html.erb (5.2ms)
  Rendered calendars/show.html.erb within layouts/application (17.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 160ms (Views: 147.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

Where could the problem be coming from: the models, the form, the controller, or somewhere else?

Comment: can you pass the server log from the console here? Can't really tell anything if there's no error message

Comment: Just added the server logs.

Comment: The log you gave is not complete. It's only the dump of show action. Post the content that appears after you submit the form. Should be something with `Started POST "/calendars/1"` or whatever.

Comment: The logs I posted were all I got when I submitted the form. However, I just implemented what @miler350 recommended in his answer, and updated the question with the new logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your post params.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.create(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render root_url
    end
  end

  protected

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:date, :time, :focus....) #put all columns that you want to submit via form here. 
  end

end
```

What you are getting is most likely a validation error because you probably require at least one field to be submitted for your post. When rails doesn't receive this, you tell it to `render` not `redirect` so you may not notice the reload.

Comment: Ok, great, I am going to do that. Is it ok if I use `private` instead of `protected`?

Comment: Also, shouldn't we include somewhere in the `post_params` the `:calendar_id`?

Comment: Yes to both. You can pass the `calendar_id` to the post_params via a hidden form. `<%= f.hidden_field :calendar_id, value: @calendar.id %>`

Comment: Perfect, this is what I have done. However, the post is still not created. I have included the logs in the question (EDIT 2).

Comment: The `Post` is not created or the post isn't associated with the calendar? Those logs look like you've created a freestanding post because calendar_id was unpermitted (?)

Comment: Well, I would say that the post is not created, since it does not appear in the `rails console` when I run `Post.last`. Plus, I believe that we do associate the post with the calendar thanks to your `<%= f.hidden_field :calendar_id, value: @calendar.id %>` line of code, don't we? (Sorry if these are basic mistakes, I am pretty new to Ruby & Rails).

Comment: I just added `:calendar_id` to the `post_params` in the `PostsController` and edited the question with the new server logs, if that may help. I must me missing something obvious, but I just don't know what.